# Laravel relationship data with different tables nased on conditions

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, subquery

i am working on a snippet but i have to check another table if that customer data exists return the data if the customer data does not exist on the employment table also return the data based on the former check then ignore the rest but if it does i want to use the condition specified to check and return that data. Here's what i have tried.

```
Customers::query()
            ->distinct('id')
            ->whereHas('quote')
            ->where(
                function ($query) {
                    $query->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('nin')->WhereNull('bvn');
                        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNotNull('nin')->whereNotNull('bvn');
                        });
                    })->orWhereHas('employment', function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('bank_statement_url')->WhereNull('mono_account_statement_url');
                        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNotNull('bank_statement_url')->whereNotNull('mono_account_statement_url');
                        });
                    });
                }
            )->paginate(30);
```

Comment: Is there an error you can share with us or can you show us the expected result vs the actual result?

Comment: @shaedrich  there is no error I am just getting mixed data. for example i am getting somebody that has either nin or bvn alongside somebody that has not

Comment: That's probably because your `orWhereHas()` applies in the latter case. Maybe you have to use AND instead of OR by just using `->whereHas()` instead of `orWhereHas()`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @shaedrich that didn't work this time it is not fetching any data at all i have looked at this thing for more than 2 days i still cannot figure out the error or what is not making it bring the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code a bit as well as changing your `orWhereHas()` to `whereHas()`:

```
Customers::query()
    ->distinct('id')
    ->whereHas('quote')
    ->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('nin')->WhereNull('bvn');
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('nin')->whereNotNull('bvn');
        });
    })->whereHas('employment', function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {  
            $query->whereNull('bank_statement_url')
            ->whereNull('mono_account_statement_url');
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('bank_statement_url')
            ->whereNotNull('mono_account_statement_url');
        });
    }
)->paginate(30);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried this and it is returning zero data with this one when I use *and* but where I use *or* I get mixed data.